# Playing Sound During Call

Tags: java, android, telephony, multimedia

I am able to play a sound during the call but at the other end the volume is pretty low.

What should I do? I have already increased the sound level to the maximum supported.

I have tried Stream, Media player and speaker Phone but am not getting the expected result.

I am stuck at this position, please help me...

Comment: You're saying you want to increase the volume past the maximum sound volume? You might want to fiddle with/replace the actual sound file then.

Comment: "but at the other end the volume is pretty low".  You want to inject sound into the uplink? I.e. play something locally, and also transfer it to the person you're talking to?  If that's the case, then you're out of luck; I haven't seen any platform that implements this functionality, and even if there are those that do there's no API in Android to enable this from an application.

Comment: I just want the sound should be played with normal volume as like our voice. In this case I can speak and hear on both the side, but as soon as I play any sound what happens it is not recognized (volume is extremely low at other side )